# Line and Button in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can we draw line and button in XAML as below image, Button content will bind to mvvm , I have added below code but not sure how can I add button with L

```
<Line Grid.Column="0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Stretch="Fill"
                      Stroke="{StaticResource BrandingBrush}"
                      StrokeThickness="2"
                      X1="0"
                      X2="0"
                      Y1="0"
                      Y2="1" />
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Expression Design` software from [Microsoft Expression Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/) suit?

Comment: if you are using a designer or not Button has 'Content' property  you can set it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would draw a Line and Buttons as the Image:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30px"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Line Grid.Column="0" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="DarkRed"
              Margin="14,0"
              StrokeThickness="2"
              X1="0"
              X2="0"
              Y1="0"
              Y2="1" />

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Width="20px" Height="20px" Margin="0,20" Content="L" Background="DarkRed" Foreground="White"/>
            <Button Width="20px" Height="20px" Margin="0,20" Content="L" Background="DarkRed" Foreground="White"/>
            <Button Width="20px" Height="20px" Margin="0,20" Content="L" Background="DarkRed" Foreground="White"/>
            <Button Width="20px" Height="20px" Margin="0,20" Content="L" Background="DarkRed" Foreground="White"/>
            <Button Width="20px" Height="20px" Margin="0,20" Content="L" Background="DarkRed" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```